# How to show a grid in full width when its right side/left side grid is hide with a button click and back to the original form?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know how to show or hide a section but got stuck going to do that. I am providing screenshot for better understanding.
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEqcm.png)

I want that left side table take the place of that right side form when I hide that form with a button click and again with a button click take in original form.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-7 counselingTableDiv" id="counselingTableDivId">
    <h3 class="text-center">Counseling Time Table</h3>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="counselingTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sat</th>
                    <th>Sun</th>
                    <th>Mon</th>
                    <th>Tue</th>
                    <th>Wed</th>
                    <th>Thu</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <span id="deleteRoutineData" class="btn btn-success">Delete All Routine Data</span>
        <span class="btn btn-success" id="setNewRoutine">Set New Routine</span>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-5 counselingSchedulesDiv" id="counselingSchedulesDivId">
        <div class="well"><h3>Enter Counseling Schedules</h3></div>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="day">Day:</label>
                <input type="text" name="day" class="form-control" id="day" placeholder="Day">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="courseName">Course Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="courseName" class="form-control" id="courseName" placeholder="Course Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="couseCode">Course Code:</label>
                <input type="text" name="courseCode" class="form-control" id="courseCode" placeholder="Course Code">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="time">Starting Time:</label>
                <input type="time" name="time" class="form-control" id="time">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="time">Ending Time::</label>
                <input type="time" name="time" class="form-control" id="time">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Here when I hide **counselingScheduleDiv** then **counselingTableDiv** will appear with full width.

Comment: add your HTML related to your issue rather than adding an image.

Comment: Bro, I have added my html and wrote again what I want to do.

Comment: can you please mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

**Say Hello to my Little Friend** [FLEX](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp) you can do a lot more with it see the demo below, use full screen to see the effect, and change the button type from `submit` to `button`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu").on('click', function() {
    $("#counselingSchedulesDivId").toggle();
  })
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.counselingTableDiv {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click Here
<i class="fa fa-bars" id="menu"></i>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col-md-7 counselingTableDiv" id="counselingTableDivId">
    <h3 class="text-center">Counseling Time Table</h3>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="counselingTable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Sat</th>
            <th>Sun</th>
            <th>Mon</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thu</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <span id="deleteRoutineData" class="btn btn-success">Delete All Routine Data</span>
      <span class="btn btn-success" id="setNewRoutine">Set New Routine</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5 counselingSchedulesDiv" id="counselingSchedulesDivId">
    <div class="well">
      <h3>Enter Counseling Schedules</h3>
    </div>
    <form action="" method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="day">Day:</label>
        <input type="text" name="day" class="form-control" id="day" placeholder="Day">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="courseName">Course Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="courseName" class="form-control" id="courseName" placeholder="Course Name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="couseCode">Course Code:</label>
        <input type="text" name="courseCode" class="form-control" id="courseCode" placeholder="Course Code">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="time">Starting Time:</label>
        <input type="time" name="time" class="form-control" id="time">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="time">Ending Time::</label>
        <input type="time" name="time" class="form-control" id="time">
      </div>

      <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: I want it when that page appears, then with a button click.

Comment: yes there is a button added on left top with label **CLICK HERE** you can click it to show hide the right section and expand contract the left table @TONMOY